# admin login programmatically in controller not working

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, login, programmatically

I am using below code to admin login programmatically in magento root folder file name `rootfolder/adminlogin.php`

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));

// supply username
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername('adminusername');

if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
  Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->renewSecretUrls();
}

$session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$session->setIsFirstVisit(true);
$session->setUser($user);
$session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success',array('user'=>$user));

if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
  echo("logged in");
}
```

THIS SAME CODE PUT IN MY MODULE FRONTEND CONTROLLER BUT NOT LOGIN IN ADMIN BY THIS CODE,WHY THIS ABOVE CODE NOT WORK IN CONTROLLER ?
PLEASE ADVICE DEVELOPERS ,I NEED TO PUT THIS CODE IN CONTROLLER IN MY MODULE

**My approach:**

First when I call `loginpost` controller action and it goes to if condition so it means admin session logged in but then I open admin section it display admin login page.
Below My custom controller which I have written code in controller.

**app/code/Module1/Test1/controller/Logincontroller.php**

```
<?php
class Module1_Test1_LoginController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction()
    { 
       $this->loadLayout();
       $this->renderLayout();
    }
    public function LoginpostAction()
    { 
       Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'adminhtml'));

    // supply username
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->loadByUsername('adminusername');

    if (Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->useSecretKey()) {
      Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/url')->renewSecretUrls();
    }

    $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
    $session->setIsFirstVisit(true);
    $session->setUser($user);
    $session->setAcl(Mage::getResourceModel('admin/acl')->loadAcl());
    Mage::dispatchEvent('admin_session_user_login_success',array('user'=>$user));

    if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
      echo("logged in");
    }
    }

}
?>
```